# Error in small sh script

Tags: linux, dialog, sh

When I run program and I click on "Yes" throws an error:

```
/home/zygis/tools/script: 26: Syntax error: ")" unexpected (expecting ";;")
```

Code:

```
DIALOG=${DIALOG=dialog}

$DIALOG --title " My first dialog" --clear \
        --yesno "You really want to run this program?" 10 30

case $? in
  0)
    if [ "$1" = "start" ];
    then
            echo "Enter OS: ";
            read OS
            echo OS
            python /home/zygis/tools/dj.py $OS
    else
        if [ "$1" = "uprint" ];
        then
            echo "usage: {start}";
            echo "example: (./boot start)";
        else
            echo "Invalid choice";
            echo "To usage use uprint";
        fi
    fi
  1)
    echo "No chosen.";
  255)
    echo "ESC pressed.";
esac
```

Comment: I think you meant `echo $OS` instead of `echo OS`. And there is no need for semicolons; they are only needed for two or more statements on one line. But you must end all but the last `case` alternatives with `;;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each case of your `case/esac` must be terminated by `;;`.  [See the man page...](http://ss64.com/bash/case.html)

```
case $? in
  0)
    if [ "$1" = "start" ];
    then
            echo "Enter OS: ";
            read OS
            echo OS
            python /home/zygis/tools/dj.py $OS
    else
        if [ "$1" = "uprint" ];
        then
            echo "usage: {start}";
            echo "example: (./boot start)";
        else
            echo "Invalid choice";
            echo "To usage use uprint";
        fi
    fi
    # Terminate.....
    ;;
  1)
    echo "No chosen.";
    # Terminate.....
    ;;
  255)
    echo "ESC pressed.";
    # Terminate.....
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use ";;" to end your cases.

```
case $? in
    0)
        echo "case 0";;
    1)
        echo "case 1";;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

Use two semicolon ;; to end each case i.e:

```
case ...
1) some_command ;;
2) other command ;;
esac
```